# How to transfer a call made using outbound call API to another number in twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

We want to call our customers using an outbound API call. It presents a simple IVR flow "Press 1 to confirm, 2 to talk to an agent". 
The call should be forwarded to another number when the user presses 2. Is this possible in Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

Heyooo, Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

That's totally possible. :) What you can do is use the [PHP helper library to make the outbound call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call?code-sample=code-create-a-call&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x).

```
$twilio->calls
  ->create(
    "+15558675310", // to
    "+15017122661", // from
    array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
  );
```

To create a call you have to define a `from` and `to` number but also an endpoint that responds the configuration [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-twilio-markup-language-twiml) for the call. In your case, the TwiML configuration for the outbound call could look like this.

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="/handle-input" timeout="5" numDigits="1">
        <Say>
            Press one to confirm and two to talk to an agent.
        </Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

This will say the message out loud and wait for a number press using the [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) verb. The important piece of the gather configuration is the `action` attribute. It defines an endpoint that will be called after the called number responded to your call and it will then include the entered information.

The `/handle-input` endpoint can then parse the response body and look for the `Digits` key. It will include the pressed digits. Depending on what number was pressed `/handle-input` can then respond with different TwiML and either say "Thank you" or forward the ongoing call to another number.

To forward the ongoing call the following configuration would do the trick.

```
<Response>
  <Dial>+4915...</Dial>
</Response>
```

---

I hope that helps. :) You can also have a look at [this detailed tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-php) covering a similar case like this.